# Why thymeleaf template does not processing?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a simple template for a print list of `Item` to the client side with spring-boot. But when I try to run it then get ERROR:

> ERROR 5434 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine
>   : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-4] Exception processing template
>   "get_all_items": Error resolving template "get_all_items", template
>   might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured
>   Template Resolvers 2017-08-22 19:37:31.302 ERROR 5434 ---
>   [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    :
>   Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
>   [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving
>   template "get_all_items", template might not exist or might not be
>   accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers] with root
>   cause
>
> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving
>   template "get_all_items", template might not exist or might not be
>   accessible by any of the configured

This is my first time when I use thymeleaf, please, help me fix this. Thank You.

This is controller:

```
@GetMapping("/get_all_items")
public ModelAndView getAllItems() {
    final ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    final List<Item> all = service.getAll();
    model.addObject("items", all);
    return model;
}
```

This is MVC config:

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/get_all_items").setViewName("all_items");
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>all</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="item: ${items}">
        <td th:text="${item.author}"></td>
        <td th:text="${item.name}"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<a href="/login?logout">Log out</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**:

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/spring_boot
spring.datasource.username=****
spring.datasource.password=****
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Comment: is this spring boot ? Can you show your application.poperties file ?

Comment: @georges van I don't know why it important but I add application.properties. Yes it spring-boot.

Comment: try to add this : spring.thymeleaf.check-template=true

Comment: Where do you store your template files ?

Comment: Please also post your TemplateResolver configuration.